# Building Program-Specific Shortcuts in UNIX

Tags: macos, unix

I have a program, called carmel, which I can run from the command line via:

`carmel -h`

or whichever suffix I chose. When loading a file, I can say:

`carmel fsa1.fst` where `fsa1.fst` is located in my heme folder, `/Users/adam/`.

I would prefer to have the default file location be, e.g., `/Users/adam/carmel/files`, and would prefer to not type that in every time. Is there a way to let UNIX know, when I type `carmel` to then look in that location?

Comment: I do have the source code. What sort of file should I look for there?

Comment: I've moved my comments into an answer.

Comment: This belongs more in superuser than StackOverflow.

Comment: @Omnifarious: indeed. I answered the question with the expectation that it would be migrated and not closed. That said, my answer is definitely for a programmer and not just a power-user.

Comment: @Johnsyweb: I was expecting it to be migrated too. :-( My close vote was a migration vote. _sigh_ People are so quick to close and so incautious. Questions are valuable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no standard Unix shortcut for this behaviour. Some applications will check an environment variable to see where their files are. but looking at [`carmel/src/carmel.cc`](https://github.com/graehl/carmel/blob/master/carmel/src/carmel.cc) on GitHub, I'd say you'd have to write a wrapper script. Like this:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# Save as ${HOME}/bin/carmel and ensure ${HOME}/bin is before
# ${carmel_bin_dir} in your ${PATH}. Also ensure this script
# has the executable bit set.

carmel_bin_dir=/usr/local/bin # TODO change this?
working_directory=${CARMEL_HOME-${HOME}/carmel/files}

if [[ ! -d "${working_directory}" ]]; then
    echo "${working_directory} does not exist. Creating."
    mkdir -p "${working_directory}" || echo "Failed to create ${working_directory}"
fi

pushd "${working_directory}"
echo "Launching ${carmel_bin_dir}/carmel ${@} from $(pwd)..."
${carmel_bin_dir}/carmel ${@}
popd
```

Alternatively, since the source is freely available, you could add some code to read `${CARMEL_HOME}` (or similar) and submit this as a pull request.

Good luck!